# P(A|B^c) given the following

Tags: probability, statistics

Given $P(A) = 0.2, P(B) = 0.6$, where A and B are mutually exclusive, find the conditional probability $P(A|B^c)$.

How do I determine this answer? I've been trying to figure it out for hours.

Comment: OK, so $B^c$ is the complement event of $B$. In other words, it's the case where $B$ hasn't happened. If $B$ hasn't happened, then the probability that $A$ has happened is $0.2$ out of $0.4$, right? Therefore, the answer is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: From what i read online cause my text book is crap, that this AnB-1/B-1 which I see to be 0.2 with my numbers Just P(A) but thats not the case. I am unable to find any formula with my current situation only ones that mention P(A|B) which don't give the right answer or any answers that I have to select from

Comment: This makes sense now thank you

Comment: You're welcome. I added it as a formal answer below...

Comment: @NoobCoder85 Hint: Draw a venn-diagram with disjoint sets A and B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so $B^c$ is the complement event of $B$.

In other words, it's the case where $B$ hasn't happened.

If $B$ hasn't happened, then the probability that $A$ has happened is $0.2$ out of $0.4$.

Therefore, the answer to your question is $\dfrac{1}{2}$.

Of course, you can also use [conditional-probability](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_probability), as explained in other answers given here...

---

Please note that $A$ and $B$ must be mutually exclusive in order for this method to work:

[image]

Comment: Actually I would say this _is_ an informal, intuitive application of conditional probability. Everyone ends up calculating $0.2/0.4$ for essentially the same reasons.

Comment: @DavidK: Yep, I totally agree. This is essentially computing conditional probability without stating it explicitly. Since all the answers went with the formal definition, I thought I'd help OP by giving a simple perspective of the problem (an intuitive one, exactly as you described it).

Comment: @NoobCoder85: See updated answer, with an additional (important) condition that must hold in order for this intuitive approach to work.

Comment: "Please note that A and B must be independent events in order for this method to work" Sorry but the method *fails* when A and B are independent. For the method to work, A and B must be disjoint (which is, in a way, an *opposite* of being independent).

Comment: @Did: So *independent* and *disjoint* are opposite terms (in probability theory)?

Comment: @Did: Yep, I see now how my terminology was wrong. Independent events - $P(A \cap B) = P(A) \cdot P(B)$. Disjoint events - $P(A \cap B) = 0$. Thanks for pointing that out... I will use OP original terminology (*mutually exclusive*) instead.

Answer (score 0):

$$P(A|B^c)=\frac{P(A\cap B^c)}{P(B^c)}\underbrace{=}_{(1)}\frac{P(A)}{1-P(B)}=\frac{0,2}{0,4}=\frac12=0,5.$$

Can you get $(1)?$